# Is it possible to extend UIAElementArray with my own methods?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I do the following:

```
function extend(destination, source) {
  for (var property in source) {
    destination[property] = source[property];
  }
  return destination;
};

extend( UIAElementArray.prototype, 
{
       each: function(f) 
       {
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) 
        {
          f(i, this[i]);
        }
       },

       findFirst: function(f) 
       {
         for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) 
         {
           if (f(this[i])) return this[i];
         }
         return null;
       },

       findLast: function(f) 
       {
         for (i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
         {
          if (f(this[i])) return this[i];
         }
         return null;
       }
} );
```

But when I try to use "each" function on the object, which I get from mainWindow.tableViews()[0].cells(), "[object UIAElementNil] is not a function" happens. How come each property, which I add to UIAElementArray.prototype, is set to [object UIAElementNil]? Such thing happens, when I run UIAutomation tests on a real device, on Simulator it works, surprisingly.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you can extend UIAElementArray (which is not, btw, objective-c). tuneup.js uses the same method you are using above and works fine, and I have used the same method to extend UIAElementArray. I can't speak to why your script is reporting you are hitting UIAElementNil, but your extension to UIAElementArray appears to be correct.

The real issue here may be "why does this work on the simulator, but not the device?". Is the device running iOS 5 or later? I've seen iOS 4.3 devices work fine (for the most part) with scripts recorded or written with 5, but I've also seen more complex scripts become unstable on 4.3 devices.

Answer (score -3):

In Objective-C you can extend any classes and add your custom methods to them using categories.

Comment: This answer misses the point entirely. The question was on UIAutomation which is JavaScript based. There is no correlation to ObjectiveC whatsoever.